# Checking if directory in HDFS is empty or not

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there any command in HDFS to check whether a directory is empty or not

Comment: hdfs dfs -ls /directory/path/

Comment: hadoop fs -count hdfs:/directory/path/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`count`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#count)**:**

```
hdfs dfs -count /path
           1            0                  0 /path
```

The output columns are: `DIR_COUNT, FILE_COUNT, CONTENT_SIZE, PATHNAME`

[`du`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#du)**:**

```
hdfs dfs -du -s /path
0  /path
```

If there are `0` byte files or empty directories, the result would still be `0`.

Answer (score 12):

```
isEmpty=$(hdfs dfs -count /some/path | awk '{print $2}')
if [[ $isEmpty -eq 0 ]];then
    echo "Given Path is empty"
    #Do some operation
else
    echo "Given Path is not empty"
    #Do some operation
fi
```