# Deleting just empty folders from hadoop

Tags: hadoop

In my perl script I need to delete just empty folder on Hadoop

What I have now is :

```
hadoop fs -rmdir $fName
```

How to extend this command to delete only empty directories?

Comment: `hadoop fs -rmdir` throws a warning if directory is not empty. I believe you should check for that warning

Comment: thank you for your comment, I have it in in the script I am not sure If i can rely on warning

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574753/checking-if-directory-in-hdfs-is-empty-or-not